# execvp() using vector<string *>

Tags: c++, shell

```
_arguments = std::vector<std::string *>();
```

I have above vector declared and I want to use it for execvp()

```
int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);
```

How do I convert the type to fit into this function?

It should be something like this

```
execvp(_arguments[0], _arguments)
```

Comment: Is there a special reason that it is a vector of *pointer to string*? Could it also be a vector of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new array of pointers to the strings' data, instead of to the `std::string`s themselves.  There are many ways to do this, but one simple way is to use another `std::vector` and a structured for loop:

```
assert(_arguments.size() > 0);  // else the executable will be invalid

std::vector<const char *> args;
args.reserve(_arguments.size() + 1);
for(string *sp: _arguments) {
  args.push_back(sp->c_str());
}
args.push_back(nullptr);  // needed to terminate the args list

execvp(args[0], args.data());
```

Comment: The second parameter to `execvp` is `char* const*`: "non-const pointer to const pointer to non-const `char`.  `std::vector<const char*>::data` returns `char const**`: "non-const pointer to non-const pointer to const `char`.  These types aren't compatible.  TLDR you need `std::vector<char*>` rather than `std::vector<const char*>` and you can't use `c_str` to access them.

Comment: @MilesBudnek "*you can't use `c_str` to access them*" - you can if you `const_cast` the pointers. Otherwise, use `&(*sp)[0]` or `sp->data()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, you can hammer that round peg into a square hole, but as you (and I, in my answer) mentioned, there are pegs that are the right shape.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use it directly.  You'll need to copy pointers to each `string`'s internal buffer into another `vector`.

Assuming `arguments_` is initialized like this:

```
std::vector<std::string*> arguments_ = {
    new std::string("mycmd"),
    new std::string("arg1"),
    new std::string("arg2")
}
```

You can call `execvp` something like this:

```
// execvp needs a NULL terminator, so make argv one element longer
// than arguments_
std::vector<char*> argv(arguments_.size() + 1);

// copy pointers to each string's buffer into the new vector
std::transform(arguments_.begin(), arguments_.end(), argv.begin(),
               [](std::string* arg) {
                   return arg->data();
               });

// The last element of argv was implicitly initialized to a null pointer
// so this isn't actually necessary.
// I just included it to be explicit
argv.back() = nullptr;

// pass a pointer to the array of char*s to execvp
execvp(argv[0], argv.data());
```

Note that this example relies on the non-const qualified overload of `std::string::data` added in C++17.  Use `&(*arg)[0]` instead if you're using an older revision of the C++ standard.

Answer (score -1):

```
_arguments = std::vector<std::string *>();
```

The standard string class manages its internal data as `char` array.
To access the internal data, call the method `data()`. The return type is `const char*`.

By the way, the pointer type for `std::string` is not necessary.

Also have a look on the reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/

Comment: how about the second argument? I understand that the first argument is _arguments[0].data() but how do we fit the vector into the second argument type which is char *const argv[]?

Comment: `char *const argv[]` is a constant pointer to `char *`. You can create a vector of `char*` (char pointers), and call the method `data()` as well.